# Unable to configure https, Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I am sure that this error can occur when apache ssl virtualhost directive doesn't contain configuration on SSLCertificateFile. However, in my situation I am pretty sure I have it configured correctly as shown in my httpd-ssl.conf below:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:443>

DocumentRoot "/home/web/htdocs"
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAdmin you@example.com
ErrorLog "/usr/local/apache2/logs/error_log"
TransferLog "/usr/local/apache2/logs/access_log"

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/my.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/private/my.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/intermediate.pem"
SSLCACertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.pem"

</VirtualHost>
```

The certificate is properly configured with 644 permission while the private key with 600.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Which error are we talking about?

Comment: Apache won't start after configuring https with error message: "Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured"

Comment: @user1677104 there is not more error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "Listen 443" to "Listen 443 http". It should solve your issue.